# Opening new browsers window blocked inside GWT application

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, gwt-rpc

In my gwt, when a clickEvent is fired, i create a webapp using rpc that i deploy  on server and i return the url which i used to open a new window...I have to do some process before opening new window , I know it's because of that that browsers block the page but I do not know how to make it functional.

```
 url= someProcess();
 Window.open(url, "Test ", "");
```

is there any tricks to make the popup not blocked?
Thanks in advance for your helps

Answer (score 0):

use a modal window rather than a popup i.e. a div overlay with the information that would have been in the popup - the browser would not be able to block this.